# How to know bandwidth of wifi router for Ubuntu by command?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, bandwidth

I'd like to know bandwidth of Wi-Fi router by command from terminal.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say *bandwidth* of the router, from your device, what do you mean? You can perform some `iperf` test to an external source to see what performance you can push through the NIC (and by proxy, the router).

Comment: I know that bandwidth of Wi-Fi is 80MHz, I opened setting Wi-Fi device and checked it. How to know that by command.